User able to approve SharePoint 2013 workflow even though not part of group
I made a simple SharePoint 2013 workflow using SPD in SharePoint 2016. When an item is created, task is assigned to Group2 for approval. There are two security groups.
Group1 - this group can create items
Group2 - this group can approve/reject items
I logged in as Group1 user and created a new item which started workflow. Then I am able to approve it even though I am not part of Group2. Why is that? I thought SharePoint automatically checks if user is part of group that can take action on workflow but seems like that is not the case.
This user has no other rights or part of any other group. Just part of Group1 with Contribute permission.

What permissions are granted for user at "site" level, contribute or anything else? Is this user account site collection administrator (SCA) in this site?

User is not site collection administrator. Only Contribute access on site level through Group1
